# Unexpected result while joining two tables in doctrine2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I am performing a join operation on two tables **Demand** and **Inventory**.
2 records in the demand table **[demand1, demand2]** correspond to the same record in the inventory table **[inventory1]**.

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
$countQuery = $em->createQueryBuilder()
              ->select('d,i')
              ->from('APIBundle:Demand', 'd')
              ->innerJoin('APIBundle:Inventory', 'i', Join::WITH, 'd.inventoryId = i.inventoryId')
```

I was expecting the query to return **[demand1, inventory1, demand2, inventory1]**
But actually the query returns **[demand1, inventory1, demand2]**

Can someone please tell me what i am doing wrong?

Comment: can you show how your entities look like?

Comment: hi, this is a link to a screeshot of my tables: http://www.imageurlhost.com/images/8at4v6pcjumomucrtikn.png

Comment: Basically it working on objects and it does not work exactly like SQL... I think you got inventory object only once cause this how UnityOfWork works (got this same id for this same object http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-object-hash.php)